# Django render template variable

Tags: django, templates, rendering

I have a field called "GOALS" that is rendered as a template variable and stored in a django model. That field is input via the admin interface and contains raw html, so in the django template there is

```
<html>
...
<P>{{ GOALS|safe }}</P}
...
</html>
```

Now I want to render this variable before it gets placed into context with my own template tag. This will allow staff to enter tags that will query the database rather than hard code variables such as the title of a project that is identified by a slug etc.

I thought of allowing them to enter template tags such as

```
GOALS = "... {{ "slug"|gettitle }} ..."
```

and rendering GOALS before it entered the context with

```
from django.template import Template, Context
html2render = "{% load episode_tags %}" + GOALS
miniTemplate = Template(html2render)
context = Context({})
GOALS = miniTemplate.render(context)
```

but loading my template tags did not work using Template this way, and this crashed with TemplateSyntaxError. So I figured I could use ElementTree and XML, but before I go ahead and do that (which is a little tedious) I wanted to ask the wider community if there was some better way to do this.

Comment: What does that `TemplateSyntaxError` say? You basically have some errors in template passed to `Template`, you have to fix them and it will work fine.

Comment: This is the out put from ipdb> p html2render
u'<p>Hello - {{ "LPPizzaToppingsRepresentingFractionsUpToQuarter"|field_from_slug }}</p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li><strong>Experience </strong>creating data displays</li>\r\n\t<li><strong>Learn </strong>how to interpret data displays</li>\r\n\t<li><strong>Develop</strong> vocabulary of comparison in Mathematics</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n'
ipdb> n
TemplateSyntaxError: Template..._slug'",)

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the solution I proposed was correct (thanks @GwynBleidD). The editor in django admin that allowed entry of the fields used widget CKEditorWidget that automatically renders the html. It was turning quotes `"` into `&quot;`. I started subclassing the widget to replace the html safe quotes, but I just don't have the time. I told the user to expect to see the `&quot;` in the source and used the following.

```
        # The GOALS field is rendered by the CKEditorWidget before it is stored.
        html2render = "{% load episode_tags %}" + GOALS.replace("&quot;", '"')
        try:
            miniTemplate = Template(html2render)
            context = Context({})
            GOALS = miniTemplate.render(context)
        except TemplateSyntaxError:
            pass
```